# Get back the same layout when when properties key as several values

Tags: java, properties

I am trying to get properties from a configuration file.

I am using PropertiesConfiguration in org.apache.commons package.

My code :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {        


        PropertiesConfiguration config = new PropertiesConfiguration();
        PropertiesConfigurationLayout layout = new PropertiesConfigurationLayout();
        try {
            layout.load(config, new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream("/path/to/file/file.ini")));
            layout.save(config, new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream("/path/to/file/file.ini")));

        } catch (ConfigurationException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

However my file looks like at the beginning:

```
# file.ini
# Comment 1

# Comment 2
[DEFAULT]

# Comment 3


[Section.1]
# param_1 
param_1          : value1.1

# param_2 
param_2  : value1.2

[Section.2]
# param_1 
param_1          : value2.1

# param_2 
param_2  : value2.2
```

and after i saved it, it looks like :

```
# file.ini
# Comment 1

# Comment 2
[DEFAULT]

# Comment 3


[Section.1]
# param_1
# param_1
param_1          : value1.1
param_1          : value2.1

# param_2 
# param_2 
param_2  : value1.2
param_2  : value2.2

[Section.2]
```

I'd like to keep the same layout but I did not find any solution.

Answer (score 0):

Opinion-based answer: be careful when **fighting** tooling: as one can easily spend (waste) a lot of time in order to bend a tool doing something it wasn't designed for.

Especially in cases like this - where you have some human readable input that seems to subject to "constantly being rewritten by machines" ... be careful to not waste your time.

Maybe that "property writer" code has good reasons to work exactly as it works today. So, just maybe: instead of changing the write-process; you could understand the transformations applied by the write process. And from there: you rework your initial input in a way that

a) still gives you a good "human readable" experience

b) doesn't drive such transformations upon "save" operations

Then both sides (humans and machines) can continue to update the underlying file.

Another option: consider to ignore the "saved" versions: keep "your version" within your source code management tool; and accept that files on  "runtime systems" look differently (because they were "reworked" by tooling at some point).